# OAuth2 flow with Spring and React

Tags: reactjs, spring-security, oauth-2.0, vite, spotify

I am building a full stack application,Spring boot in the back and React + Vite in the front but I am stucked on the oauth flow. I want to connect my app to the Spotify API, and I am having problems with it. I don’t know how the authentication flow should go.
I know the basics of oauth2 with spring boot and thymeleaf but i haven’t found any info to add a client like react

I have tried to: react/home-redirect> spotify auth endpoint -redirect> react/callback -fetch->
Spring/{redirect uri configured in yml} but i have an cors error issued in location spotify auth server. Thats weird because i have opened all origins in my spring cors configuration

Could anyone give me some advice?
Thx

Comment: You should look for BFF pattern. Your React app is just the fronend (browser), you need also a OAuth2 client (your Spring Boot application). Spotify is the OAuth2 resource server and apparently the OAuth 2 authorization server.